# Composite multiple images together onto one image with ImageMagick

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagick

I'm really new to using imagemagick, so I am probably getting things entirely wrong.

I want to load in 10 images, and composite them together onto a grid, two rows of 5 images like this:

[image]

All the images are the same dimensions so no issues there, but I'm struggling even managing to load more than one image.

I have tried the following:

```
$src1 = new \Imagick('../'.$fileSelection[0][3]);
$src1->writeImage("./output.png");
$src2 = new \Imagick('../'.$fileSelection[1][3]);
$src2->writeImage("./output2.png");

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $src1;
echo $src2;
```

This seems to output just the first image on the page and nothing else.

Where am I going wrong? How do I load in all ten images, and how to I composite them together?

I found the following code:

```
$src1 = new \Imagick("./src1.png");
$src2 = new \Imagick("./src2.png");

$src1->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$src1->setImageArtifact('compose:args', "1,0,-0.5,0.5");
$src1->compositeImage($src2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MATHEMATICS, 0, 0);
$src1->writeImage("./output.png");
```

But I got nothing on the page/blank.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You need to i) Create a 'canvas' image of the final output size you want. ii) Load each of the images, and composite into the canvas image iii) send that canvas image to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Imagick::appendImages`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php) to build the grid by iterating over each column & row.

```php
<?php
define('WIDTH',  300);
define('HEIGHT', 400);

$canvas = new Imagick();
for ($row = 0; $row < 2; $row++) {
  $stack = new Imagick();
  for ($column = 0; $column < 5; $column++) {
    // For fun, let's create some colors
    $color = sprintf('hsl(%.02f, 50, 100)', $column*99.99+$row*66.66);
    $stack->newImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, $color);
  }
  $stack->resetIterator();
  $rowImage = $stack->appendImages(FALSE);
  $canvas->addImage($rowImage);
}
$canvas->resetIterator();
$result = $canvas->appendImages(TRUE);
$result->writeImage('/tmp/out.png');
```

[image: First Example]

[`Imagick::borderImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.borderimage.php) can be used to add spacers, but if we are already iterating over each image, than we might as well just create spacers to append between.

```php
<?php
define('WIDTH',  300);
define('HEIGHT', 400);
define('SPACE',   35);

$canvas = new Imagick();
for ($row = 0; $row < 2; $row++) {
  $stack = new Imagick();
  $stack->newImage(SPACE,1,'white');
  for ($column = 0; $column < 5; $column++) {
    $color = sprintf('hsl(%.02f, 50, 100)', $column*99.99+$row*66.66);
    $stack->newImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, $color);
    $stack->newImage(SPACE, 1, 'white');
  }
  $stack->resetIterator();
  $rowImage = $stack->appendImages(FALSE);
  $canvas->newImage(1, SPACE, 'white');
  $canvas->addImage($rowImage);
}
$canvas->newImage(1, SPACE, 'white');
$canvas->resetIterator();
$result = $canvas->appendImages(TRUE);
$result->writeImage('/tmp/out.png');
```

[image: Second Example]

Comment: This is amazing and incredibly helpful. I'm working with this code now to attempt to output my images. Thank you so much.